# Implementing File upload in a QML WebView

Tags: qt, webview, qml, symbian

I am trying to implement file upload to a remote server using a form in a QML Webview for the Symbian platform. The form contains an HTML file upload form field. When i run it on the device (Nokia N8), the webview loads up but clicking the browse button for file upload field does nothing.

This works well if i go directly to the webpage using a desktop browser and other form elements like a text field works in the web view.

Is there an issue with QML webview and html file upload field? Are there other ways sung QML to upload files to remote servers?

Comment: Check the C++ based qml-http-uploader component here: https://code.google.com/p/qml-http-uploader/

Answer (score 0):

May not be a solution but this can be tried. Since accessing File systems in Symbian requires certain capabilities like **ReadUserData, ReadDeviceData**, etc. that can be added to the application and tried.